# React Checkbox Group - Set initial state from API

Tags: reactjs

I have a `CheckboxGroup` component which takes in an `options` array prop and generates `CheckboxInput` components. On page load I make a call to an API which returns an array of pre-selected checkboxes (delivered to the `value` prop). Depending on the logged in user, this call can return an empty array or a selection of previously selected checkbox options.

The following code successfully takes the response of the API call and sets the relevant checkboxes to 'checked'. The issue I have is that this code doesn't allow me to make changes to the checkboxes after page load (clicking a checkboxes has no effect).

I think there is also some disconnect between the initial selectedCheckboxes state and the value of the API call but I read that setting props as initial state is an anti-pattern (e.g. `selectedCheckboxes: props.value,`).

```
export default class CheckboxGroup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedCheckboxes: [],
    };
  }

  addCheckboxToSelected = (id) => {
    if (this.state.selectedCheckboxes.includes(id)) {
      // Remove checkbox from array and update state
      const filteredArray = this.state.selectedCheckboxes.filter(item => item !== id);
      this.setState({ selectedCheckboxes: filteredArray });
    } else {
      // Add checkbox to array and update state
      this.setState({ selectedCheckboxes: this.state.selectedCheckboxes.concat(id) });
    }
  }

  checkIfSelected = (checkboxValue) => {
    const preSelectedCheckboxes = this.props.value;
    let selectedBool = false;
    preSelectedCheckboxes.some(function(object) {
      if (object.id === checkboxValue) {
        selectedBool = true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    return selectedBool;
  }

  render() {
    const { label, name, options } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="form-group form-inline">
        <span className="checkboxgroup-heading">{label}</span>

        <div className="form-group-container">
          {options.map(object => (
            <CheckboxInput
              key={object.value}
              name={name}
              label={object.label}
              onChange={this.addCheckboxToSelected}
              value={object.value}
              checked={this.checkIfSelected(object.value)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the stateless CheckboxInput component

```
const CheckboxInput = ({ name, label, onChange, value, checked }) => {
  return (
    <div className="field form-group filter-input">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={value}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={() => onChange(value)}
        checked={checked}
      />
      <label htmlFor={value} className="form-control">{label}</label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code snippet. This might help. Let me know if you have questions.

```js
const CheckboxField = ({checked, onChange}) => {
  return (
    <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={ev => onChange(ev.target.checked)} />
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      options: [{id: "1", checked: true}, {id: "2", checked: false}]
    };
  }
  
  handleCheckboxChange(checked, option) {
    const {options} = this.state;
    
    var cOptions = [...options];
    for(var i in cOptions) {
      if(cOptions[i].id == option.id) {
        cOptions[i].checked = checked;
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      options: cOptions
    }, () => console.log(options));
  }

  render() {
    const {options} = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div>
        {
          options.map(option => {
            return (
              <CheckboxField key={option.id} checked={option.checked} onChange={value => this.handleCheckboxChange(value, option)} />
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```